# fecha rfc 822 time zone

Tags: python, django

estoy trabajando con una API externa y necesito pasar una fecha PERO sólo me acepta la fecha con formato **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
RFC 822 time zone** ; La armé en *un String pero no me la acepta*, porque tiene que ser tipo Date. La tengo que pasar por un json a la url y no encuentro cómo obtener ese formato.
Estoy trabajando con Python/Django.

Probé isoformat() pero como me devuelve un str, no me sirve...

Comment: El estándar RFC 822 especifica el formato de una **cadena** que representa una fecha. Por tanto si tienes que generarlo en ese formato, has de generar una cadena. Quizás es que el formato no era el correcto. ¿Puedes poner el código que has probado?

Comment: `v = datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 31, 2, 59, 59, tzinfo=<UTC>)
def vencimiento_formato(v):
 year = str(v.year)
 if v.month < 10:
  month = '0' + str(v.month)
 else:
  month = str(v.month)
 if v.day < 10:
  day = '0' + str(v.day)
 else:
  day = str(v.day)
 vencimiento = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + '-' + 'T23:59:00+0000'
 #print('VENCIMIENTO', vencimiento)
 return vencimiento
`

Comment: Y el dato en json: **last_due_date** Tipo: **Date** 
Formato: **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
RFC 822 time zone** -> Fecha de último vencieminto.

Comment: La función que hice me devuelve un string, pero tiene que ser formato Date.. No encuentro cómo pasarlo a tipo Date

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es un error de concepto, y de que el formato que generas no se ajusta a lo que el otro extremo (la API externa) espera.

## Concepto: Fechas en json

Cuando transmites una fecha en JSON lo que transmites es una **cadena** siempre, pues JSON no tiene de forma nativa un tipo fecha, sino que representa las fechas como cadenas de caracteres. Por tanto, tu función que convierte una fecha dada en cadena es la forma correcta de abordar el problema (si bien la función puede ser mucho más simple gracias al uso de `.strftime()` como mostraré luego).

Pero por otro lado, al otro extremo de tu conexión, quien recibe el JSON espera que esa cadena tenga un formato muy concreto, y ahí es donde creo que fallas. El error de que no es un `Date` correcto, debe interpretarse como que la cadena que la envías no ha podido ser decodificada para crear con ella un objeto de tipo `Date` (¿me equivoco o ese otro extremo está hecho en Java?)

## Formato esperado y formato recibido

El error creo que proviene de que el formato esperado es, como tú mismo indicas:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

pero lo que estás generando tiene este otro formato:

```
2019-07-31-T23:59:00+0000
```

el cual se diferencia del esperado en que:

- Añade tras los segundos un *offset* horario (`+0000`) que no se esperaba
- No tiene una `Z` tras los segundos.

Si la cadena fuese esta otra, creo que sí sería aceptada:

```
2019-07-31-T23:59:00Z
```

## Generación de la cadena desde python

Como decía antes, la función `strftime()` sirve para convertir un objeto python de tipo `datetime` en una cadena con el formato que necesites. Se usaría así:

```
def vencimiento_formato(v):
    return v.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
```

Para conocer más sobre el formato que usa esta función mira su [documentacion](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)